# Accessing Intel Ive Bridge's True Random Number Generator

Tags: java, random, intel

I have figured out that Intel Ivy Bridge supplies a True Random Number Generator in hardware.

Now I am mainly programming in Java and wondering what the ways are to access it?

Does `java.util.Random` try to use an in-built hardware RNG for example if one is present?

Comment: Unless it is written somewhere, you would need to find if the method is intrinsic and look for the code in the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this project: https://code.google.com/p/lizalab-rdrand-util/

It extends `java.util.Random`, so it can be used just as well. Seems to only work in Linux and Mac OSX right now.

[Source](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/09/16/rdrand-library-for-java)